# Append data to the HTML existing table.. Without loose current heading

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

Am doing a project in Asp.Net Web API..

Now i have a problem that when am trying to append data from the database to the existing HTML table My current HTML table header are replacing by the data which i call from database..........

please help me to solve this issue..

Here by appending code bellow...

```
function GetsearchDetails(EmpDetails) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/suppliermaster' + '?EmpDetails=' + EmpDetails,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {


            $('#tblSearchdetail').empty()
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#tblhead");
                $("#tblSearchdetail").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].Cust_Code_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_Name_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_Address_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_PhoneNo_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_Email_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_ContactPerson_V + "</td><td>" + data[i].Cust_Fax_V + "</td><td>" + " <a href='#' class='edit'>EDIT</a>" + "</td><td>" + " <a href='#' class='Delete'>Delete</a>" + "</td></tr>");
            }


        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }


    })

}
```

My HTML table code:

```
<table class="span12 table table-bordered" style=" overflow:scroll" id="tblSearchdetail">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Phone No</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Conact Person</th>
                            <th>Fax No</th>


                        </tr>


                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

> Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements
>   from the DOM.

This line remove everything in your `<table>`

`$('#tblSearchdetail').empty()`

If you want to remove your rows `<tr>` each time, try to use:

`$('#tblSearchdetail').remove('tr')`

or something like that.